# Using Xcode, why is my git branch called [32master[m?

Tags: xcode, git, branch, git-branch

When I create a new project in Xcode 4.6 and turn on git - my default branch is strangely named "[32master[m". This is the name that appears in the Organizer->Repositories->Branches area.

When I use iTerm and go into the project directory, typing:

```
git branch
```

shows

```
* master
```

I know I'm close because when I type:

```
git branch | od -c
```

I get

```
0000000    *     033   [   3   2   m   m   a   s   t   e   r 033   [   m
0000020   \n                                                            
0000021
```

Any ideas on how I can get a "normal" named master branch?

The consequence of this is that I can't push, branch or manipulate the repo in any way.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101096

Answer (score 4):

If the output of

```
$ git config --global color.branch
```

is "always", try running

```
$ git config --global color.branch auto
```

The extra bytes you see are used to colorize the output of `git branch`; setting the option to "auto" will make `git branch` use the colorization only if the output is intended for the terminal, and not used by another program (in this case, XCode).

Comment: Thank you so much. There was an entry in my ~/.gitconfig as follows: [color] ui = always. Removing this entry resolved my issue!

Answer (score 2):

The bytes that you're seeing only mean that git is highlighting the branch name "master" in green, using [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). So, what is it that happens when you try to push, branch, or otherwise manipulate the repo?

If you delete the project's derived data as in [Xcode 4 Git—"This file does not exist at the requested revision"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101096), then can you branch?

Comment: When I try to branch, Xcode complains "This file does not exist at the requested revision". After I add a remote and try to push it complains: "fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in [32master[m:[32mmaster[m"!