# Preserving Xcode workspaces between machines?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've started developing my iOS app across two machines. A MBP and an iMac. I'm using an only repository which works almost identical to how GitHub works. So Source Control features built into Xcode 5 work perfectly too.

Here's the thing though - I sometimes change Xcode preferences or my work space / schemes etc and when I get to the other machine - obviously these settings need to be setup again.

Is there a way to sync the workspace / preferences of my Xcode from one machine to the other?

Answer (score 0):

personally I work with `github` and the job is done automatically by pushing and pulling the data from the git. So it's possible to do it, maybe you should include the `storyboard` and `Project Settings` (`project.pbxproj` for me) in your git sync files.

Comment: The repository I am working off, it based off GitHub and thus, everything git can do, so can my repo. Question is, what files should be included?

Comment: I was checking on mine by doing a commit and it seems that the storyboard (if you changed it) and the "Project Settings" (for you it's this one I guess) in your project : `project.pbxproj`

Comment: When including project settings I get: "This file does not exist at the requested revision" this is when selecting the file in the commit window of Xcode

Comment: I can't really help you with this problem, but maybe you can get some help for this problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101096/xcode-4-gitthis-file-does-not-exist-at-the-requested-revision